# NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:dateStyle:timeStyle does not return a correctly localized string in IOS Simulator

Tags: ios, ios7, localization, ios-simulator, nsdateformatter

I've used the following method in my code to get a localized string for a `NSDate` object:

```
todayDate = [NSDate date];    
todayDateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:todayDate
                                                 dateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle
                                                 timeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
```

I've run the app on the *IOS Simulator* with the Locale set to *English* and it shows:
*January 4, 2014 at 11:10:40 AM GMT+1* then I've changed the Simulator language to *Italian* and relaunched the *App*: the localized strings within the *Storyboard* correctly changed to *Italian* but the string produced by the `NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:dateStyle:timeStyle:` method is always localized in *English*.. Is it something related to the simulator or am I missing something? I don't have a developer certificate so I can not test on a real device.

Comment: Probably a little late, but make sure you are actually changing the Region setting, not just the Language setting, on the simulator. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem that you have, but I've also struggled with the `localizedStringFromDate:dateStyle:timeStyle:`class method before. My tip is to use the instance methods instead, then you have more control of what is happening:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;

NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date];
NSString *todayDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:todayDate];

NSLog(@"Todays date localy: %@", todayDateString);
```

Good luck!